# Cloudfoundry - how to configure external database with jhipster?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster

I use jhipster to generate project. And it's amazing.
I can deploy my application on cloudfoundry and everything work fine.
Now, I would like to connect my application to an external data base. How can I proceed ?
I've done some modification in application-dev.yml or prod if I choose prod profile but my application still using the cloudfroundry service dingo for the database.
Is there any way to connect my application to a external postgreSQL data base when my project is availaible on cloudfoundry ?

Thank you for your support

Comment: Where is located your database?

Comment: The CloudDatabaseConfiguration configuration class will override your application.yaml config. Try removing the file (or commenting or deactivating).

Comment: Thank you. I'va also modify manifest.yml and delete service line.